# CompletableFuture thread id for 'supplyAsync' and 'thenAccept'

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have written a small program to test the CompletableFuture behavior and I am not clear how the threads are created and used in execution of the tasks.

```
package com.my.testprog.concurrjava;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class CompFuture {

    ExecutorService firstExecService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    ExecutorService secondExecService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public CompFuture() {
    }

    public String returnSalutation(String param) {
        System.out.println("RS: " + Thread.currentThread());
        return param + " Hello my";
    }

    public void returnGreetings(String salutation) {
        System.out.println("RG: " + Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println("RG: " + salutation + " Friend!");
    }

    public void testMe(String start) {
        System.out.println("TM: " + Thread.currentThread());
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> returnSalutation(start), firstExecService)
            .thenAccept(s -> returnGreetings(s));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompFuture compFuture = new CompFuture();
        compFuture.testMe("Java");

        compFuture.firstExecService.shutdown();
        compFuture.secondExecService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it prints the following output:

```
TM: Thread[main,5,main]
RS: Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
RG: Thread[main,5,main]
RG: Java Hello my Friend!
```

My understanding is that it would use the same thread to invoke 'supplyAsync' and 'thenAccept' methods. However, above result indicating that only 'supplyAsync' is being executed in a separate thread, where as 'thenAccept' is run in main thread.

Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: I would not have expected it to use the same thread, but one from either the same executor or from the default ForkJoinPool.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47711550/2711488) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46062939/2711488).